# Image cannot exceed device width on iPhone 5

Tags: html, css, iphone, flexbox, width

I have is that why images on iPhone 5 cannot exceed its device width, while I set the widths of my images as 200%. It looks as I expected on Chrome's dev mode, yet not on real device. Though I haven't tested other devices, I guess other ones with width smaller than 320px would have same problems?

---

[This is the screenshot from iPhone 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxkpb.jpg)

[And these are screenshots from Chrome's dev mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1FtH.png)

Here's the relevant html snippet

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=1">

<div class="landing">
    <div class="landing-container">
        <div class="landing-title-container" >
            <h1 class="landing-title">Let's Make Impacts</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="landing-img-container">
            <img class="landing-img landing-front" src="/materials/landing.png" alt="landing">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant sass snippet

```
.landing {  
    width: 100%;
    height: 120vw;

    .landing-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .landing-img-container {
        height: 120vh;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        overflow: hidden !important;    
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .landing-img {
            width: 200%;
            height: auto;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;                   
        }
}
```

---

Feel free to check my code with Chrome's dev mode if these snippets are not thorough enough.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using flexbox on the image's parent in order to center the image which is going to affect scaling. The default property for `flex-shrink` will prevent the image from being wider than the container.

Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the image. This will still allow the centering to take place but without limiting the size of the image.

It's quite common to see `max-width: 100%;` applied to images as well which you may need to undo.

```
.landing-img {
    width: 200%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;  
    flex-shrink: 0;  
    max-width: none;               
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really helped me! 
But adding `flex-shrink` not works on my case, so I also add `flex-basis`, and the problem's solved!